# linux script to combine 3 lines at a time

Tags: linux, parsing, terminal, format

I'm having trouble reformatting some data.  It exists as:

```
name
info 1
info 2
name
info 1
info 2
name
info 1
info 2
name
info 1
info 2
name
info 1
info 2
```

I need it as

```
name, info 1, info 2
name, info 1, info 2
name, info 1, info 2
name, info 1, info 2
```

I currently use a combination of find, awk, grep, and sed to get the data from multiple larger files.  It would be nice to simply pipe (append) a reformatting solution to my existing terminal "1 liner".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by piping the data through a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read name && read info1 && read info2 || break
    echo $name, $info1, $info2
done
```

That's short enough that you could incorporate it directly into your existing scripts or even type it at the command line if you were inclined to do.